# What does (*ptr)[10] mean?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
void main()
{
    int (*d)[10];
    d[0] = 7;
    d[1]=10;
    printf("%d\n",*d);
}
```

It should print `10` but compiler is showing error such as follows:

> test.c:4:7: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[10]’ from type ‘int’

Note that I have included some errors , not all.

Comment: [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) says *d is a pointer to array of 10 ints*. Also, `void main` is a bad thing for any hosted environment.

Answer (score 6):

As noted by chris, `d` is a *pointer* to an *array*. This means you use the variable improperly when you access it, but also that you will access random memory unless you assign `d` to point to a valid array.

Change your program as follows:

```
int main(void)
{
    int (*d)[10];  /* A pointer to an array */
    int a[10];     /* The actual array */

    d = &a;  /* Make `d` point to `a` */

    /* Use the pointer dereference operator (unary prefix `*`)
       to access the actual array `d` points to */
    (*d)[0] = 7;
    (*d)[1] = 10;

    /* Double dereference is okay to access the first element of the
       arrat `d` points to */
    printf("%d\n", **d);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, [] is the same as *, the pointer syntax. Thus the following lines are the same:

```
int** array2d1;
int* array2d2[];
int array2d3[][];
```

To relate to a closer example, the main function has the following popular forms:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){ ... }
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){ ... }
```

Thus

```
int (*d)[10]
```

is the same as

```
int* d[10]
```

which is the same as

```
int** d;
int firstArray[10];
d = &firstArray;
```

Effectively, you are creating a pointer to a pointer (which is a pointer to an array) and allocating the first pointer to an array that 10 elements. Therefore, when you run the following lines:

```
d[0] = 7;
d[1] = 10;
```

You are assigning the 1st array's address to 7 and the second array's address to 10. So as Joachim has mentioned, to assign values, you need to deference twice:

```
(*d)[0] = 7
(*d)[1] = 10
```

Which says "Assign 7 to the 0th index at the value pointed by d". I hope that makes sense?

Comment: `int (*d)[10]` and `int* d[10]` are far from being the same thing. In the former case, you have a pointer to an array of 10 ints (i.e. `*d` points to a block that can host 10 ints), while in the latter, you have an array of 10 int pointers, but there is absolutely no guarantee that `d[0]`,`d[1]`,... points to consecutive addresses.

Comment: Oh right I see what you are saying. I did not know the difference. But if I were to say use int* d[10] and use malloc() from i=0 to i=9 to allocate 10 int** and each int* would allocate 10 slots, would that be in a continuous memory? Thanks for the details btw.

Comment: No (well there's no guarantee at least). Two consecutive call to malloc are not required to give back two consecutive blocks: in your example, `d[0][10]` is not the same as `d[1][0]` (and would in fact yield an undefined behavior, as you trying to make an access outside of the first malloc'ed block, while the latter is of course perfectly legitimate).

Answer (score 1):

`d` is a pointer to an array of 10 ints.

`int (*d)[10]` is the declaration for a point to an array of 10 ints.

vs.

`int *d[10]`, which is an array of 10 int pointers.

For more complex syntax like this (usually involving pointers), I use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) to help me decode it.

Answer (score 0):

It's used in this form
int d[10]

I guess you are mistaken that d must be a "kind of pointer" and therfor you put an * before the d.
But that's not what you want. You wan to name an array of integer and the notation for that is seen above.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of pointer can get confusing sometimes in C.

Consider an array `int d[6] = {0,1,2,3,4,5}`

Then, *d is equivalent to d[0]. d is itself an pointer to an array and *d dereferences that pointer and gives us the value.

Hence, following code would print the same values:

```
int main()
{
    int (d)[10];
    *d = 7;
    *(d + 1)=10;
    printf("%d\n",*d);
    printf("%d\n",d[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
7
7
```

Please see http://codepad.org/LYY9ig1i.

If you change your code as follows:

```
#include<malloc.h>
int main()
{
    int *d[10]; //not (*d)[10]
    d[0] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *) * 10);
    d[0][0] = 7;
    printf("%d\n",d[0][0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sizeof(int)` instead?